# PHP code for printing receipt in receipt printer in windows 7

Tags: php, printing

the printer functions like `printer_open()` etc are not working in my windows 7 . I use php 5.0
and it says call to undefined function. can anyone help me on how to print receipt or first of all sending print jobs to printer.

Answer (score 0):

It the `undefined function` error message means the printer extensions are not installed.

The docs contains instructions for installation:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/printer.installation.php

Comment: i have installed all the dll extensions and addes it in php.ini but still not getting it

Comment: A DLL for this PECL extension is currently unavailable. See also the building on Windows section. from 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/printer.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

php_printer.dll is not supported anymore in PHP > 5.3.x. so make sure you have PHP 5.3.x, not 5.4.x and go here to download the associated dll http://likepie.net/2012/php_printer-dll-and-php-5-3-9/

Comment: Link provided is no longer available.